# Force UTF-8 handling for std::string in fmt

Tags: c++, fmt

In my C++17 project, I have a std::string which is known to contain UTF-8 encoded data. Is there any way to force fmt to treat its data as UTF-8 such that this works as expected?

```cpp
fmt::print("{:-^11}", "あいう");
// should print "----あいう----", currently prints "-あいう-"
```

Comment: I think you need `std::u8string` for handling utf-8 properly on general level, which is only available in C++20. I remember there was some special API in fmt dedicated to utf-8 which you could use.

Comment: Would you happen to know where I can find this API? I can't see anything of the sort when I search for it.

Comment: This just works in {fmt} now. Also avoid `char8_t` at all costs - it will be broken in C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 handling in {fmt} was recently improved and your example now works with the `master` branch:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("{:-^11}", "あいう");
}
```

prints

```
----あいう----
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass field width as the next argument and calculate it yourself:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <cstring>
int main() {
    fmt::print("{:-^{}}", "あいう", 8 + std::strlen("あいう"));
}
```

Comment: So I take it there's no way to use UTF-8 strings in a generalised manner?

Comment: Well, I would like not to answer such question, because firstly "In a generalized manner" is broad and is inviting opinion based answer and secondly, because I don't have much experience in utf8 strings and in fmt library. I think providing your own `fmt` overload for a custom class that would handle utf8 strings is not that much work. I just wanted to point a simple workaround.